# html linking a spreadsheet(CSS) using url_for

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have my static folder with main.css inside and am calling it in the HTML file using url_for. The problem is that when i edit my css file and reload the application(flask py) the css doesn't actually get changed. When i tried to use url_for but my edits didn't get applied. So, I tried directly putting in the file path. The code could identify the css file, but when I checked the application, the css wasn't applied at all.

BTW I am using vs code if that affects anything.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>OpenAI Quickstart</title>
  <link
    rel="shortcut icon"
    href="{{ url_for('static', filename='dog.png') }}"
  />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}" />
</head>

<body>
  <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='dog.png') }}" class="icon" />
  <h3>Homepage</h3>
  <form method = "POST" action="http://localhost:5000/symptoms">
    <input type="submit" value = "Check Ailment"></input>
  </form>
  <form method = "POST" action="http://localhost:5000/test">
    <input type="submit" value = "test"></input>
  </form>


</body>
```

main.css:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "ColfaxAI";
  src: url(https://cdn.openai.com/API/fonts/ColfaxAIRegular.woff2)
      format("woff2"),
    url(https://cdn.openai.com/API/fonts/ColfaxAIRegular.woff) format("woff");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "ColfaxAI";
  src: url(https://cdn.openai.com/API/fonts/ColfaxAIBold.woff2) format("woff2"),
    url(https://cdn.openai.com/API/fonts/ColfaxAIBold.woff) format("woff");
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}
body,
input {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #353740;
  font-family: "ColfaxAI", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
.icon {
  width: 34px;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #202123;
  margin: 16px 0 40px;
}
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 320px;
}
input[type="text"] {
  padding: 12px 16px;
  border: 1px solid #10a37f;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}
::placeholder {
  color: #8e8ea0;
  opacity: 1;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  padding: 12px 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #10a37f;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.result {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Sometimes problems like this can be caused by Cache. Have you tried clearing your browser Cache? If you are in Chrome with dev tools open you can right click the reload button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser keeps the old css file in cache for faster load times. You should try deleting the cache.
https://help.overdrive.com/en-us/0403.html
Press CTRL+SHIFT+DEL and delete only the cache.

Comment: Helped with the first part of the problem but am still unable to understand why using the path without url_for doesnt work

Comment: Also is there a way to set it to not store the cache of a specific website(in this case localhost) or do i manually clear it every time?

Comment: Inspect Element>settings(the right gear icon)>scroll to network>disable caching while DevTools is open